# How to straighten divs lined up next to each other

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to straighten up the divs right next to each other? I've tried but it all seems slightly proportion and I would like a way of keeping each column well positioned next to each other (despite any changes that may occur).

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/j3cY5/2/

**UPDATE:** It seems jQuery datepicker isn't working in the sample :-(

**HTML**

```
<div class="schedule_wrapper">
    <div class="schedule_item">
        <div style="background-color:#08011c; color: #FFF; padding: 5px;">Task</div>
        <div style="height: 20px; padding-top: 4px;">Item 1</div>
        <br>
        <div style="height: 20px; padding-top: 4px;">Item 2</div>
        <br>
        <div style="height: 20px; padding-top: 4px;">Item 3</div>
        <br>
        <div style="height: 20px; padding-top: 4px;">Item 4</div>
        <br>
        <div style="height: 20px; padding-top: 4px;">Item 5</div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule_item">
        <div style="background-color:#08011c; color: #FFF; padding: 5px;">Due Date</div>
        <div style="height: 17px; padding-top: 2px;">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker1" style="width: 100px;
                    height: 10px;" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="height: 17px; padding-top: 2px;">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker2" style="width: 100px;
                    height: 10px;" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="height: 17px; padding-top: 2px;">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker3" style="width: 100px;
                    height: 10px;" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="height: 17px; padding-top: 2px;">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker4" style="width: 100px;
                    height: 10px;" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="height: 17px; padding-top: 2px;">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker5" style="width: 100px;
                    height: 10px;" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule_item">
        <div style="background-color:#08011c; color: #FFF; padding: 5px;">Status</div>
        <div>
            <select style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>----</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <select style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>----</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <select style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>----</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <select style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>----</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <select style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">
                <option></option>
                <option>----</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="schedule_item">
        <div style="color: #FFF; padding: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.schedule_wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.schedule_item {
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
}
body {
font-family: Verdana;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background: #52A8E8;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4081AF;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 21px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: auto;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:active {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #377AD0;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
input[type="submit"] + a {
    margin-left: 22px;
}
```

Comment: try setting some divs to "display:inline-block"?

Comment: @captainrad Like so? http://jsfiddle.net/j3cY5/3/

Comment: Is it possible (depending upon your requirements) to work with rows instead of columns? If I understand what you are looking to do (each row proportional to one another) you may also want to change the height of the update input.

Comment: @methuselah To resolve the `datepicker` issue, remove the `hasDatepicker` class from the target input elements.

Comment: Looks like you're building a table. Why not use a <table>?